# Timeline on Y axis, with chart.js

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, chart.js

**I am having trouble locating a time scale on the Y axis of my graph**.

The objective of this graph **is to compare, between different machine operators, the time (minutes and seconds) that were necessary to manufacture the same piece.**

**When wanting to graph only an empty graph is observed, showing me only the names of the operators on the X axis.**

[image: chart-time]

Using a sql query that I do in my controller
I get this information:

```
{
"pieces": [
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Miguel",
"time": "00:02:00",
"denomination": "Eje 340 d19",
"quantity": 60,
"rol": 2
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"time": "00:04:00",
"denomination": "Eje 340 d19",
"quantity": 30,
"rol": 2
}
]
}
```

As you can see in the query **for the same part manufactured by different operators, there is a different machining time, just that is what I want to dump on my graph and I do not know how to spend the minutes (`"time": "00:02:00","time": "00:04:00",`) on the Y axis**

In this getChartDataPiece () function I use ajax to receive my array pieces.
I am also stating time as an array and just there my machining times are stored, this is how I run it:

```
function getChartDataPiece(name) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/dashboard/getChartPiece/' + name,  
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {             
            console.log(response);
            var time = [];           
            var operator = [];                    

            for (var i in response.pieces) {
                time.push(response.pieces[i].time);              
                operator.push(response.pieces[i].name);                                
            }       
            renderChartPiece(operator, time);           
        },       
        error: function (response) {       
            console.log(response.time);
            console.log(response.operator);
        }
    });
}
```

**I'm not sure if those machining times (minutes and seconds) are recognizable by chart.js**

This is how I'm trying to graph with function renderChartPiece(operator, time):

```
function renderChartPiece(operator, time) {
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById("times").getContext('2d');
    var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {  
        type: 'bar',    
        data: {                       
            labels: operator,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Partida',
                data: time,
                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                yAxisID: 'Tiempos',
                xAxisID: 'Operarios',
            }],
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    id: "Tiempos",
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true                       
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Tiempos'
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    id: "Operarios",                   
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Operarios'
                    }
                }],
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Ordenes de trabajo"
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom',
                labels: {
                  fontColor: "#17202A",                
                }
            },
        }        
    });  
}
```

**Please I NEED your help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use values in seconds for Y-axis.

```
function timeToSeconds(time) {
  var parts = time.split(":");
  var valueInSeconds = 0;
  var secondsInTimeUnit = [3600, 60, 1];
  for (j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
    valueInSeconds = valueInSeconds + secondsInTimeUnit[j] * parseInt(parts[j]);
  }
  return valueInSeconds;
}
```

than in your code:

```
function getChartDataPiece(name) { 
//.....
            var time = [];           
            var operator = [];                    

            for (i = 0; i <  response.pieces.length; i++) {
                time.push(timeToSeconds(response.pieces[i].time));              
                operator.push(response.pieces[i].name);                                
            }
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/112g/pen/GRpqKEd?editors=1010)

However the Y axis values are in seconds.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719641) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54799972) some tips how to change it. Don't forget to upvote these two;)

Here is what you need to change:

```
function renderChartPiece(operator, time) {
//...
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
//...
                   ticks: {
                     beginAtZero:true,
                     stepSize: 30, //step every 30 seconds
                     callback: function(label, index, labels) {
                       if (parseInt(label) % 30 == 0) {
                         //convert seconds to mm:ss format
                         var mins = parseInt(parseInt(label)/60);
                         var seconds = parseInt(label) - mins*60;
                         return mins+":"+(seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") +seconds;
                       } else {
                         return "";
                       }
                     }
                   },
```

[And here is final solution](https://codepen.io/112g/pen/pojbovy?editors=1010)

---

EDIT 2020/04/18:

Tooltip values in previous solution had values is seconds.

You can find more [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html)

```
  //...
  options: {

        //add this for tooltips
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                    if (label) {
                        label += ': ';
                    }
                  var mins = parseInt(parseInt(tooltipItem.yLabel)/60);
                  var seconds = parseInt(tooltipItem.yLabel) - mins*60;
                  mins =  mins+":"+(seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") +seconds;                  
                  return label + mins;
                }
            }
        },
        scales: {
        //....
```

Corrected version [here](https://codepen.io/112g/pen/pojbWWX?editors=1010)

Comment: Great, I'm just seeing your answer, at this moment I can't try the solution. I can hardly verify your answer, I give you my vote, thank you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you have given me a quick solution.
Could you check your final snippet?
I run the snippet, and look over label something like this: ```Miguel tiempo: 120 ```  ```Luis tiempo: 240 ```

So how could this appear to me:  ```Miguel tiempo: 2:00 ```  ```Luis tiempo: 4:00 ```

Comment: Again thank you very much for your answer, difficult for me to solve alone!!